# SoftLayer API error - Invalid price id for 960 GB SSD in dal10

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to order a monthly bare metal server with multiple 960GB SSDs and am getting the following API error

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): The price for 960 GB SSD (3 DWPD) (#156775) is not valid for location dal10.

I see the option when ordering through the portal UI so I'm not sure what the issue is. I can provide some debugging output from my script if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this article http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you

Basically all the prices have a property called "pricingLocationGroup", this property specifies in what datacenters the price is valid.

In the case of datacenters located in "Dallas" you need to use prices whose "locationGroupId" = null. You can order the item using the portal. because the portal uses the correct price id.

So you need to pick up another price for the item whose "locationGroupId" = null.

Regards